# Parsing Problems while Data Scraping

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

Think im having a problem with my parsing. Im using JSoup and Java in Android Studio. Im trying to data scrape info from a local html file and display on my app. But when i run the app the data i want doesnt appear. I want to display the times like "9:00" and "9:15". Also "Sound", "P2016" and "P.Mann". The html looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head><title>timetable.html</title><meta http-equiv='content-  disposition', content='attachment;filename=timetable.html'>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/octet-stream" />

   <style>body {background-color:white;} body,td { font-family: arial; }                     </style></head> 
   <data>
   <body>
   <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
  <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
  </data>
  <tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td>
  <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
  <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
  <tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td>
  <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
  <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
  <tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td>
  <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
  <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
  <tr>
  <td><table border='0' width='100%'>                                                                        <tr>  
  <td width='40%' align='left' valign='middle'><font face='arial' size='3'><b>The Year<font size='1'> </td><td    width='20%' align='center' valign='middle'><font face='arial' size='1'>ICOM</td><td width='40%' align='right' valign='middle'><font face='arial' size='2'><b>Weeks selected for output: 26 (22 Feb 2016-28 Feb 2016)</td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   <table  cellspacing='0'  border='1'>
   <tr>
   <td></td>

   <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:45</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
      <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" rowspan='1'   bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>  

    <font color='#FFFFFF'>Mon</font></td>
<td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='12' rowspan='1' >

    <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><font color='#FF0000'>Sound</font></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
    <col align='right' />
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>P2016</font></td>
    <td align='right'><font color='#008000'>P.Man</font></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </td>
<td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
<td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='4' rowspan='1' >
```

This is what that java looks like:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
    import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {

        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Mobile Newest\\JSoup\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\filename.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
        Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        for (Element td : tableElements) {
            textView.setText(td.text());
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
 }
```

Anyone have any idea why it doesnt come up on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, everytime you call `textView.setText(td.text())`, the textview is replaced by the current `td.text()`, so in the end you will only be able to see the **LAST** `td` element text of your html file, which is essentially a blank space

Comment: so what will i change it to so that it will print what i need it to?