# The Right Data isn't displaying for my App- Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping data from a local HTML page in Android Studio and instead of the right info being displayed all that its displaying is a blank screen. Anyone know how to display the data i have scraped? Below is a the main piece of code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
        InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.html"));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        String str;
        while ((str=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(buf.toString());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Elements tableElements = doc.select("td[colspan='1']");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        for (Element td : tableElements) {
            sb.append(td.text() + "\n");
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
        textView.setText(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
HTML

```
         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
   <head><title>timetable.html</title><meta http-equiv='content-disposition', content='attachment;filename=timetable.html'>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/octet-stream" />

  <style>body {background-color:white;} body,td { font-family: arial; }        </style></head>
     <data>
           <body>
          <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
             <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
      </data>
            <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
    <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
    <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
    <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
    <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
    <col align='left' /><col align='center' /><col align='right' />
    <tr>

        <td><table border='0' width='100%'><tr><td width='40%' align='left'  valign='middle'><font face='arial' size='3'><b>The Year<font size='1'> </td><td width='20%' align='center' valign='middle'><font face='arial' size='1'>ICOM</td>      <td width='40%' align='right' valign='middle'><font face='arial' size='2'>      <b>Weeks selected for output: 26 (22 Feb 2016-28 Feb 2016)</td></td><td></td>   <td></td>
     </tr>
      </table>
         </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       <table  cellspacing='0'  border='1'>
        <tr>
       <td></td>

      <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:00</font>          </td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>9:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>10:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>11:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>12:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>13:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>14:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>15:45</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:00</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:15</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:30</font></td>
<td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'><font color='#FFFFFF'>16:45</font></td>
            </tr>
        <tr >
        <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" rowspan='1' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#FFFFFF'>Monday</font></td>
        <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='12' rowspan='1' >

         <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><font color='#FF0000'>Sound</font></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
     <col align='left' />
     <col align='right' />
     <tr>
     <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>P2016</font></td>
     <td align='right'><font color='#008000'>P.Man</font></td>
      </tr>
       </table>
     <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
     <col align='left' />
     <tr>
     <td align='left'><font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font></td>
     </tr>
     </table>

      </td>
     <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
     <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
     <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
     <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
     <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='4' rowspan='1' >

     <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
     <col align='left' />
       <tr>
     <td align='left'><font color='#FF0000'>Ship</font></td>
     </tr>
      </table>
    <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
    <col align='right' />
    <tr>
    <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>P2015</font></td>
    <td align='right'><font color='#008000'>K.Loin</font></td>
     </tr> 
      </table>
     <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
    <col align='left' />
     <tr>
     <td align='left'><font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font></td>
       </tr>
      </table>

      </td>
      <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='12' rowspan='1' >

      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
       <col align='left' />
      <tr>
      <td align='left'><font color='#FF0000'>Mobility</font></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
      <col align='left' />
      <col align='right' />
      <tr>
      <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>P2222</font></td>
      <td align='right'><font color='#008000'>D.Met</font></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
      <col align='left' />
      <tr>
      <td align='left'><font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font></td>
      </tr>
     </table>

      </td>
     </tr>
```

Its a timetable, this is just monday.the rest is too long but it continues on like monday does I want to display are the times like 9:00 and 9:15,Monday,Sound , P2016, P.Man,Ship,K.Lion, P2015

Comment: Are you getting the right output in the console? Is your TextView visible if you just set some text to it?

Comment: can you share some logs ? like what do you get when you print buf.toString() and what do you have in the doc ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this, this is based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385967/parsing-problems-while-data-scraping):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(buf.toString());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Elements tableElements = doc.select("td[colspan='1']");
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
for (Element td : tableElements) {
    sb.append(td.text() + "\n");
    System.out.println(td.text());
}
textView.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Got an error with the getText() bit, do i have to define it in content_main?

Comment: Replace it with `text()`

Comment: still not getting it to display anything, i have updated the code above to show my local html page i scrape with this code

Comment: You missed my last line of code: `textView.setText(sb.toString());`

Comment: updated the java code, even with it added its not displaying anything

Comment: Ca you post your full html and what are you trying to display?

Comment: theres a lot of html code, give me a second and i will update it